# Multithreading Objects with WMI Queries and Some Other Queries

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wmi

I am currently in the process of constructing a server monitoring application using **C# 4.0**, which I queries hardware information (CPU/RAM/HDD usages) using WMI and some other libraries to query services like FTP and HTTP. The hardware data query is encapsulated in the Server class and software services are in the Service class, each of them having a timer that queries their corresponding server and services periodically on an interval set by me.

However, as most of you might know that WMI queries are taking a lot of time to be done, and software service queries will block the caller as it is being carried out. Now that I am almost finish constructing these classes (Server and Service), it is time for me to think about integrating them into a UI.

I am planning to use a WPF front-end, possibly the Navigation template of the nRoute framework. However I have very little knowledge about WPF and multi threading. What I would want to inquire is how can I instantiate every Server and Service objects on a different thread so they do not hang the application? And is it possible for me to add them to a Collection and then display them as a list on the front end?

Any suggestion and advise is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options available.

- Use [thread pool](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling)
- Use [Tasks](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism)
- Use [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- Manually create threads [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Once working with Collections, consider using [concurrent collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).

In your situation I will start with thread pooling or manually creating the threads, and if that doesn't work for you I will consider the other options.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, will try it out and see how it goes. Any other suggestions are welcomed.